# How can I get SD-Card size?

Tags: android, memory, android-sdcard

I want to get size of SD-card(removable) and InternalMemory. I use two methods. But both of them return me InternalMemory size.

**Method for InternalMemory size:**

```
public static String getTotalInternalMemorySize() {

    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
    return formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize);

}
```

**Method for SD-Card size:**

```
public static String getTotalExternalMemorySize() {
  
    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
    return formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize);
 
}
```

**Method for formating in readable for users format:**

```
private static String formatSize(long size) {
    String suffix = null;

    if (size >= 1024) {
        suffix = "KB";
        size /= 1024;
        if (size >= 1024) {
            suffix = "MB";
            size /= 1024;
        }
    }

    StringBuilder resultBuffer = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(size));

    int commaOffset = resultBuffer.length() - 3;
    while (commaOffset > 0) {
        resultBuffer.insert(commaOffset, ',');
        commaOffset -= 3;
    }

    if (suffix != null) resultBuffer.append(suffix);
    return resultBuffer.toString();
}
```

How can I get SD-Card size?

Comment: Supply full path of sd card instead of full path of internal/external memory.

Comment: @blackapps Can you say me how?

Comment: You know how you can supply a path. I dont understand what you asked.

Comment: @blackapps I mean, I don't know how to get the path to the SD card on different devices programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs().